# Как предотвратить переадресацию youtube?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect

Хочу с ноута перейти на страницу https://m.youtube.com/, но происходит редирект на страницу https://www.youtube.com/. Помогите справиться.

Comment: передавать соответствующий user-agent?

Answer (score 1):

На примере Chrome:
Ctrl+Shift+C

[image: Пример]